# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<T>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to extract future from a steam, but he made an error

Return stream is good

```
  Future<T> post<T>(options){

       return _request(options["url"],"POST",data: options["data"]).single;
  }

  Stream<T> _request<T>(url,method,{data}) {

    return Stream.fromFuture(ApiDio().request(url,method: method,data: data))
         .transform(ResponseTransformer());
  }
```

[image]

fix:

```
Future<T> post<T>(options){

       return _request<T>(options["url"],"POST",data: options["data"]).single;
  }
```

The first method should add generic

Comment: you need to map your response to the object UserAuthEntity

Answer (score 0):

Your Class declaration will be something like this:

```
class YourClass {
String name;
   YourClass(this.name);
   factory YourClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return YourClass(json['name'] as String);
   }
}
```

To convert it from your HttpResponse:

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: await setHeaders());
dynamic parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
final yourClassObject = YourClass.fromJson(parsed);
```